# Internal hard drive not showing after possible power failure

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I have a Seagate hard drive stopped working after a possible power failure.

It is not showing in BIOS. I checked Disk Management, it shows as Disk 1 Unknown Not Initialized without available space. The disk won't show up in tools like minitool.

Is there a way to fix this or restore the data to another hard drive?

Update 1: I just tried Seatools, which can't find the hard drive as well.

Update 2: testdisk and photorec won't detect the hard drive.

Comment: What diagnostics, if any, have you run on the drive? Try SeaTools. Have you checked if you can hear the drive spin up?

Comment: What power failure happened? Did the machine just turn off and now the hard drive doesn't work, or did a circuit breaker in your house go and cut the power?

Comment: @Mokubai My 2 year old pressed the power button multiple times, next thing I noticed was the hard drive not showing.

Comment: It could be that the PSU is fried, and one of the 5/12V Molex connector outputs is shot. Do you have another PC you can try it in? Or a USB caddy?

Comment: @Appleoddity Haven't done any diagnostics yet, I'll give SeaTools a go now, I just opened the case and reboot the PC, what I heard from the hard drive is like an noncontinuous spin sound for a few second, then silence.

Comment: @spikey_richie I'dont have the appropriate cable, but I just ordered one, I can try it tomorrow.

Comment: Not intialized indicates the file system was lost, TestDisk might help, but if BIOS doesn’t detect it then professional data recovery might be your only option (no, what they do, can’t be done by you)

Comment: @Ramhound Just tried TestDisk, it won't detect the hard drive as well.

Comment: Since the disk isn't detected by 3 programs, you have to bring it to local data recovery labs for recovery.